# can't find kotlin file in my flutter project

Tags: flutter, kotlin, stripe-payments

I am developping a flutter app which contain firebase stripe function,

I can't find kotlin file to change `FlutterFragmentActivity` instead of `FlutterActivity` in `MainActivity.kt`, I find only java file.

Anyone have a solution please ?

[here is my directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUQq9.png)

I searched a solution but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [an issue on the flutter_stripe project](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/issues/1017) this seems expected:

> you can go to the java folder open mainactivity.java and extend Flutter fragment activitiy: https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/app/FlutterFragmentActivity.html.

I don't believe there's a way to get a Kotlin version of that file out of the box.